# How to disable power on by keyboard on my B550 AORUS MASTER mother board

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios, motherboard

So I have been using this computer for about 2 weeks and I noticed that my computer boots up when I use press a key on my keyboard. I have tried to navigate the BIOS settings, but I cant seem to find any options for "Boot from Keyboard" (or anything of similarity). You can consider the BIOS Boot settings in this image: [image: BIOS Boot settings]

Comment: I have not come across such a setting.  There is, however, start up when a key is pressed.

Comment: Do you shutdown the computer or set it to sleep/hibernate?

Comment: I came across something like "wake up on keypress" on a different bios. hth

Answer (score 0):

Go to: settings>Platform Power

Look for: ●Erp

```
      ●Wake on LAN
```

This will turn off the keyboard turning on pc and USB power disabled on shutdown.

This work for me and hopefully it will help you as well.